# Display list buttons in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to add a button

```
if array.length! = 0
```

and what I wrote does not work.

```
$scope.pages = 0;
if(array.length != 0) {
   $scope.pages++;
}
```

and in AngularJS I made:

```
  <div ng-repeat="page in pages">
    <button ng-click="loadProducts(1)">{{ page }}</button>
  </div>
```

I think in AngularJS can't after number, repeat buttons

Comment: what exactly you want?

Comment: If $scope.pages = 4 print 4 buttons in html

Comment: ng-repeat works like you have multiple objects in an array. not on numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this,

```
 <div ng-repeat="i in loadProducts(pages) track by $index">
```

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('ReqWebApp', [])

myApp.controller('ReqAppController', function ReqAppController($scope) {
$scope.pages = 4;
$scope.loadProducts = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);   
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ReqWebApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>New Request</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ReqAppController">
    <div ng-repeat="page in loadProducts(pages) track by $index">
    <button>test{{ page }}</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a list of buttons, do the following:

**JS**:

```
  $scope.pages = 0;
    $scope.pageArray=[];
    if(array.length != 0) {
     for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
       $scope.pages++;
       $scope.pageArray.push($scope.pages);
    }

    }
```

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-repeat="page in pageArray">
    <button ng-click="loadProducts($index)">{{ page }}</button>
 </div>
```

**JS Fiddle**:http://jsfiddle.net/5dybgrvv/

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it without adding content to your controller, like this :

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.number = 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="x in [].constructor(number) track by $index">
    <button ng-click="loadProducts(1)">{{ $index }}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```